# C Programming :: accept() works and then doesn't, in stress-testing

Tags: c, sockets, stress-testing

I am coding what I thought would be a simple C socket program.  The code will act as a primitive server.  It needs to create a listening socket, and then each time it is contacted, it needs to **accept()** the incoming connection, then spin off a thread to handle some basic processing.  The threading and processing part I more-or-less have working, but the **accept()** part breaks down after the code successfully handles some initial connections..  This is a problem, because I anticipate that this program will need to run continuously and may have to process a lot of incoming requests.

Some environmental stuff first:  I’m working on a Ubuntu box, and my code is compiled with GCC:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/me/socketProject# gcc -v
...
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4)
root@ubuntu:/home/me/socketProject#
```

My **main()** function sets up a listening socket, then starts an infinite loop.  For every connection that comes in, it tries to **accept()** and then pass the work off to a detached thread:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
   int             sock = -1;
   struct          sockaddr_in address;
   int             port = 12345;
   connection_t*   connection;
   pthread_t       thread;

   // Create the listening socket
   sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
   if (sock <= 0){
      fprintf(stderr, "%s: error: cannot create socket\n", argv[0]);
      return -3;
   }

   // Bind socket to port
   address.sin_family = AF_INET;
   address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
   address.sin_port = htons(port);
   if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) < 0){
      fprintf(stderr, "%s: error: cannot bind socket to port %d\n", argv[0], port);
      return -4;
   }

   // Listen on the port
   if (listen(sock, 5) < 0){
      fprintf(stderr, "%s: error: cannot listen on port\n", argv[0]);
      return -5;
   }

   // Listen forever...
   while (1){
      // Accept incoming connections
      connection = (connection_t *)malloc(sizeof(connection_t));

      printf("1)  [[ sock: %d -- address: %s -- addr_len: %d ]]\n", connection->sock, &connection->address.sa_data, connection->addr_len );

      connection->sock = accept(sock, &connection->address, &connection->addr_len);

      printf("2)  [[ sock: %d -- address: %s -- addr_len: %d ]]\n", connection->sock, &connection->address.sa_data, connection->addr_len );

      if (connection->sock <= 0){
         printf(" *** PROBLEM!!!  Value of errno: %d\n ", errno);
         free(connection);
      }
      else{
         // Start a new thread but do not wait for it
         pthread_create(&thread, 0, process, (void *)connection);  // process() omitted
         pthread_detach(thread);
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Pretty textbook stuff.  I worked out all the logic and got everything working perfectly when there is only one incoming connection.

But then I started stress-testing, and immediately realized I had a problem.  I wrote a client program that send X number of test requests, all in a row.  The above server code works fine for a few initial requests, but then breaks down.  Here’s the output:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/me/socketProject# ./server
        *** 1)  [[ sock: 18954128 -- address:  -- addr_len: 0 ]]
        *** 2)  [[ sock: 7 -- address:  -- addr_len: 16 ]]
        *** 1)  [[ sock: 18970816 -- address:  -- addr_len: 0 ]]
        *** 2)  [[ sock: 8 -- address:  -- addr_len: 16 ]]
        *** 1)  [[ sock: 18962080 -- address:  -- addr_len: 0 ]]
        *** 2)  [[ sock: 9 -- address:  -- addr_len: 16 ]]
        *** 1)  [[ sock: 18962112 -- address:  -- addr_len: 0 ]]
        *** 2)  [[ sock: 10 -- address:  -- addr_len: 16 ]]
        *** 1)  [[ sock: 18954064 -- address:  -- addr_len: 0 ]]
        *** 2)  [[ sock: 11 -- address:  -- addr_len: 16 ]]
        *** 1)  [[ sock: 18954160 -- address:  -- addr_len: 0 ]]
        *** 2)  [[ sock: 12 -- address:  -- addr_len: 16 ]]
        *** 1)  [[ sock: 18907120 -- address:  -- addr_len: 0 ]]
        *** 2)  [[ sock: 13 -- address:  -- addr_len: 16 ]]
        *** 1)  [[ sock: 18950880 -- address:  -- addr_len: 0 ]]
        *** 2)  [[ sock: 14 -- address:  -- addr_len: 16 ]]
        *** 1)  [[ sock: 18961856 -- address:  -- addr_len: 0 ]]
        *** 2)  [[ sock: 15 -- address:  -- addr_len: 16 ]]
        *** 1)  [[ sock: 18957136 -- address:  -- addr_len: 0 ]]
        *** 2)  [[ sock: 17 -- address:  -- addr_len: 16 ]]
        *** 1)  [[ sock: 18957168 -- address:  -- addr_len: -518793662 ]]
        *** 2)  [[ sock: -1 -- address:  -- addr_len: -518793662 ]]
 *** PROBLEM!!!  Value of errno: 22
        *** 1)  [[ sock: 18961856 -- address:  -- addr_len: -518793662 ]]
        *** 2)  [[ sock: -1 -- address:  -- addr_len: -518793662 ]]
 *** PROBLEM!!!  Value of errno: 22
        *** 1)  [[ sock: 18961856 -- address:  -- addr_len: -518793662 ]]
        *** 2)  [[ sock: -1 -- address:  -- addr_len: -518793662 ]]
 *** PROBLEM!!!  Value of errno: 22
        *** 1)  [[ sock: 18961856 -- address:  -- addr_len: -518793662 ]]
        *** 2)  [[ sock: -1 -- address:  -- addr_len: -518793662 ]]
 *** PROBLEM!!!  Value of errno: 22
        *** 1)  [[ sock: 18961856 -- address:  -- addr_len: -518793662 ]]
        *** 2)  [[ sock: -1 -- address:  -- addr_len: -518793662 ]]
 *** PROBLEM!!!  Value of errno: 22
        *** 1)  [[ sock: 18961856 -- address:  -- addr_len: -518793662 ]]
        *** 2)  [[ sock: -1 -- address:  -- addr_len: -518793662 ]]
 *** PROBLEM!!!  Value of errno: 22
        *** 1)  [[ sock: 18961856 -- address:  -- addr_len: -518793662 ]]
        *** 2)  [[ sock: -1 -- address:  -- addr_len: -518793662 ]]
 *** PROBLEM!!!  Value of errno: 22
        *** 1)  [[ sock: 18961856 -- address:  -- addr_len: -518793662 ]]
        *** 2)  [[ sock: -1 -- address:  -- addr_len: -518793662 ]]
 *** PROBLEM!!!  Value of errno: 22
        *** 1)  [[ sock: 18961856 -- address:  -- addr_len: -518793662 ]]
        *** 2)  [[ sock: -1 -- address:  -- addr_len: -518793662 ]]
 *** PROBLEM!!!  Value of errno: 22
        *** 1)  [[ sock: 18961856 -- address:  -- addr_len: -518793662 ]]
        *** 2)  [[ sock: -1 -- address:  -- addr_len: -518793662 ]]
 *** PROBLEM!!!  Value of errno: 22
        *** 1)  [[ sock: 18961856 -- address:  -- addr_len: -518793662 ]]
```

You see the problem.  In the above example, something happens after about ten successful requests, then **accept()** starts complaining of **ERRNO 22**.  A quick Google search revealed that **ERRNO 22** is “***EINVAL: Invalid argument***”, which obviously isn’t good.

I’ve done some simple socket programming from my student days, but I’ve never had a problem with **accept()** before.  I’m really puzzled.  It looks to me like N-1 requests arrive and are successfully processed by **accept()**.  But then the Nth appears, **accept()** doesn’t like it, and the socket gets corrupted.  How or why, I don’t know.

**accept()** is complaining about "invalid argument(s)".  But the client is literally sending the exact same test message over and over.  How can the N-1 connections present valid arguments, but the Nth, N+1th, N+2th... argument be invalid?  That blows my mind.

Some observations:

- This is a black-and-white phenomenon.  By that, I mean that the
  socket works perfectly 100% of the time, but then something bad
  happens with **accept()**, and then the socket never works again.
- I’ve run a lot of tests, and there’s no telling how many successful
  connections I’ll get when I start a new test.  I’ve had as many as 88
  successful connections before the socket stops working.  In another
  test, I only had 2 successful connections before the socket went
  belly-up.  The average number of successful connections before the
  socket breaks is about 17.
- My client test program does not try to space out the requests it
  sends; it simply opens a socket and starts bombarding my server
  program at top speed.  I’m doing this because I want to stress-test. 
  But perhaps my client program is sending test requests too fast for
  the server to keep up…?
- It is also possible, I suppose, that the client program is causing
  the problem.  I don’t think so, because it just sends the same test
  message over and over and it never throws an error.

Has anyone ever seen an issue like this?  I’ve been looking on SO for about an hour, but I can’t find another post where **accept()** works, and then doesn’t.

Any help/advice is appreciated.

Comment: Side note: Don't run your stuff as root ... use a user account.

Comment: @DanielJour Yes, that's a great point.  Good catch, will be sure to do.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialize `addr_len` to the size of `addr`.

If you look at the manpage for accept, under the listed `errno` values; `EINVAL` if `addrlen` is invalid (e. g. is negative)

(blown mind):  it isn't the same arguments.

You are calling `malloc()` which might return uninitialized memory.

Whatever value you set `addrlen` to how many bytes of the address can be copied into address; 0 means none.

Comment: For those following this thread:  I added "connection->addr_len = 20;" as a line IMMEDIATELY after malloc()'ing the connection struct.  Now the socket stays up like a champ.

Comment: Thanks so much mevets!